# Django Only non-relations and foreign keys permitted

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to create a script here that looks at my staff table list that analyzes staffs email addresses and compares it to the login names in the system to assign them to their classrooms, but my script keeps on crashing.

What's the goal ?
The goal is I have a table called sections, sections are classrooms . Each classroom has a teacher assigned to them. However, in order for the teacher to see the classrooms they are assigned to, im linking this by the users login name which is their email address. However, although my logic from a print statment does work on my queries, it fails on updating the many to many fields. Here is my code.

```
FUNCTION

def AssignLoginToSection():
  users = User.objects.all()
  for user_email in users:
    email = user_email.email 
    print('Getting Email addresses in system.')
    if Section.objects.filter(staffpsid__email = email):
      section = Section.objects.filter(staffpsid__email = email)
      print("Found Matching Login Name.")
      print('The following sections were found with this users email.', section)
      Section.objects.filter(staffpsid__email = email).update(teacher_username= email)
      print('Added user login name to section.')
    else:
     print("No matching login name.")
  return("Done")   

MODELS

# Section Information Stored
class Section(models.Model):
    sectionpsid= models.CharField(primary_key = True, default = "", max_length = 50)
    schoolpsid = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = "" ,)
    coursepsid = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = "" ,) 
    termpsid = models.ForeignKey(Term,on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = "" ,) 
    section_number = models.CharField(default = "", max_length = 50)
    expression = models.CharField(default = "", max_length = 50)
    external_expression= models.CharField(default = "", max_length = 50)
    staffpsid = models.ForeignKey(Staff,on_delete = models.PROTECT, default = "" ,) 
    gradebooktype = models.CharField(default = "", max_length = 50)
    teacher_username = models.ManyToManyField(User)
 
# Staff Information Stored
class Staff(models.Model):
    staffpsid= models.CharField(primary_key = True, default = "", max_length = 50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = "")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = "")
    staff_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = "")
    email = models.EmailField(default = "", unique = True)
    staff_cell = models.CharField(max_length = 12, default = "")
    users_dcid = models.CharField(max_length = 5, default = "")
```

The Error I get is Cannot update model field <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: teacher_username> (only non-relations and foreign keys permitted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ManyToManyField works with add or delete method

instead of :

```
Section.objects.filter(staffpsid__email = email).update(teacher_username= email)
```

use:

```
section.teacher_username.add(user_email.id)
```

Comment: Error message i got for this was... 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: edited last answer. your using many to many and you should use add method. in many to many you can't use update or save method but you can use add and delete method

Comment: i had to do another for loop for section since there was multiple items, but this worked. Thank you Reza

Comment: Glad I was able to help